# How to interpret a ML training output

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm a beginner in Machine Learning and I'm learning through working on Kaggle competitions.  I've started off with the famous Titanic survival problem and through trial-error/getting help from others, I am able to train my data but my question is:  How do I make sense of the output and proceed to the next stage?

So this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_path = "C:\\Users\\Omar\\Downloads\\Titanic Data\\train.csv"
train_data = pd.read_csv(train_path)

train_data['Sex'] = pd.factorize(train_data.Sex)[0]

columns_of_interest = ['Survived','Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age']
filtered_titanic_data = train_data.dropna(axis=0)

x = filtered_titanic_data[columns_of_interest]
y = filtered_titanic_data.Survived

train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=0)

titanic_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
titanic_model.fit(train_x, train_y)

val_predictions = titanic_model.predict(val_x)
print(val_predictions)
```

And this is the output that I'm getting (1 survived - 0 died):

```
1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.
```

But I don't know how to use this output to proceed to the next stage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "next stage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now compare your `val_predictions` with `val_y` and see how many you got right!

You used `train_x, train_y` to find the pattern, you fit it on `val_x` and now you want to see how good your model is!

There are multiple ways to go about this! You can choose your evaluation metric!

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

accuracy_score(val_predictions, val_y)
```

Here is the link to what `accuracy_score` represents! http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#accuracy-score

Accuracy score is an evaluation metric! Going forward, you can also you `GridSearchCV` to automatically search for the optimal parameters to maximize or minimize your evaluation metric.

You can read about it here:

1. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html
2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269300/why-does-sklearn-grid-search-gridsearchcv-return-random-results-on-every-executi

Comment: @desertnaut habits.

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks man.  I've accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote?

Comment: @OnurOzbek I did it just now.

Comment: Thank you very much